# How to create surrogate Key in BigData

Tags: bigdata

We are planning to move our Transactional data into BigData platform and do the analysis there. One challenge we faced is how can we create auto-increment in bigData. We need it to generate Surrogate keys.

Answer (score 1):

Most common approach is to use a [type 3 UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29), i.e. a pseudo-random identifier with extremely, extremely low collision chance.

If you really need sequential (or at least monotonic) identifiers for some reason, then you will need to generate them from a single source, and this single source may need to be separated out as a service, e.g. [Twitter Snowflake](https://github.com/twitter/snowflake/tree/snowflake-2010).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I agree with [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) approach.

> but please make sure that you refactor your ER model to have proper balance between normalised and deNormalised entity.

If you move your existing application ER model as is in BigData architecture then it would slow down performance as it might have to do joins with BigTable.

> Also make sure that you know your Key to access data is strong and not changing when data is updated while storing in NoSql database

This link will give u some idea about above

- [Transition-RDBMS-NoSQL](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Transition-RDBMS-NoSQL/)
- [relational-databases-vs-non-relational-databases](http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2015/08/relational-databases-vs-non-relational-databases/)